# Create a relation for each record in a table

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table of users in an SQLite database, as well as a few other tables: `roles`, and `userRoles`. `userRoles` contains a foreign key relation linking user IDs to roleIDs. Each user can have 0-to-many roles.

I have an existing database with a user table, and I have added the role tables after the fact. I need a query that will add each user to a "default" role.

TO do this, I have written a query:

```
INSERT INTO userRoles (roleID, userID)
SELECT id from users, SELECT id from roles WHERE roleName = 'default';
```

I have also tried specifying the values:

```
INSERT INTO userRoles (roleID, userID) VALUES (
    SELECT id from users,
    SELECT id from roles WHERE roleName = 'default'
);
```

However it is incorrect. Specifically SQLite is telling me:

```
Error: in prepare, near "SELECT": syntax error (1)
```

This is SQLite version 3.37.2

Answer (score 1):

You can `SELECT` only from the table `users` and use a scalar subquery to get the `id` of the `'default'` role name:

```
INSERT INTO userRoles (userID, roleID)
SELECT id, (SELECT id FROM roles WHERE roleName = 'default') FROM users;
```

or, with a join:

```
INSERT INTO userRoles (userID, roleID)
SELECT u.id, r.id 
FROM users u JOIN roles r
WHERE r.roleName = 'default';
```